# Warm Up Question

Tags: tuba, warm-up

If I warmup two hours before a performance and take an hour break, will that have me properly warmed up for my performance or do I need to do a little more RIGHT before my performance?

Comment: Do you mean warm up for a full hour then take an hour off before the show? What instrument do you play?

Comment: If you're playing tuba in a concert band, your ability to play it before your recital has already been decided for you. (For example, you need to lug your tuba to the venue first, then the bandleader may help you tune mere minutes before you perform.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two hour warm-up is way too long before a performance, and an hour of nothing just before is also too much. Brass players I play with generally have ten minutes just before the gig. In fact, one of the best players used to turn up for the gig with five minutes to go, and I never heard a bad note from him. Not recommended, though, and I bet when he was bandleader he came down hard on players who did just that.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is refering to something that is a warm-up and then a cool-down. Also, one hour of warm-up seems to long. Ten minutes seems better. That one hour will probably make you have less energy for the performance